# Rails 3 - Nested Forms, using Builder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following:

My Controller:

```
  def new
.
.
    @teammembers.each do |teammember|
        request = @request_thread.requests.build(:recipient_id => teammember.user_id, :full_name => 'Billy Bob T')
    end
```

My View:

```
<%= f.fields_for :requests do |builder| %>

    <div class="field">
        <%= builder.label :full_name %>
        <%= builder.check_box :recipient_id, :checked => false %>
    </div>      
<% end %>
```

The nested form for request only holds the user_id, not the user.name... Problem is in the nested form, I need to show the user.name next to the check_box. So I tried adding a virtual attribute in the model (attr_accessor :full_name), so I could use full_name but I can't see to access that in the nested form (inside builder).

Any tips or suggestions from the pros?

Thanks

Comment: Something is up with check_box, it doesn't seem to work with fields_for. I want to use the check_box to tell Rails to create the recipient record or not.

Comment: Why isn't the check_box getting the recipient_id value?

Comment: This doesn't work either: "<%= item.check_box :recipient_id, :value => :recipient_id  %>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
User.find(:recipient_id).name
```

EDIT: I hope i understood your question ..